# How to Track Journey flow of an ecommerce?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

can anybody tell me how to check the journey flow of a website?

Like a person who enters on a website from the homepage.
2. Then click on the banner 1
3. Move to the category 3.
4. Then Open the product 2. 
5. Select the product 2 variant 4
6. And bought the product.

How to check this journey flow. Because we can't do this google analytics.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you need to add GA events to your code / or use GTM.

Since your question is a little open ended:

You may want to look at solutions other than GA since you may want to track individual behaviours.
GA only gives you aggregated anonymised data (unless you try to to create custom user labels).

Check out trackers like Kissmetrics, or piwik etc.

Comment: So, we can get the individual data from Piwik. Do you have any other recommendations such as iTracker or Otracker

Comment: @P082  I've only used GA and Kissmetrics myself. A few friends have experimented with Piwik and have in the past told me that it was great for downloading and clustering the data, etc. 
Figure our what questions you want to ask the data, then figure out the best tool to implement tracking and to extract insights.